# Why would my olive oil smell like chipotle peppers?

Tags: flavor, olive-oil, smell, pepper

I bought some Napa Valley Naturals organic extra virgin olive oil (not actually from Napa Valley -- it's from Spain). We're used to buying this brand, and in fact usually buy 9L at a time. But this box... well, the best I can describe is that it smells and tastes like it has been infused with chipotle peppers!

**So, my question:** What could cause this? How can I tell? Possibilities I've considered so far:

- It's an olive oil defect, but it's not a common one
- Wherever it was packed, there was contamination from chipotle-infused oil
- It's some other contaminant, and I shouldn't even be eating it
- This is legit olive oil, but a different variety or whatever

It's not *bad*, but it's not what I want -- I'm used to this brand being moderately good quality. I'll be calling them and inquiring about any recalls, whether there was something different about the lot, etc., but I also want information from an impartial source.

(Also interested in whether there are independent testing labs I could send a sample to without too much trouble/expense. I'm in the Boston area, for reference.)

Comment: Is there any discoloration? (i.e. the oil seems to have a different color than yellow or greenish yellow)

Comment: FWIW, Napa Valley Naturals does not make any type of chili-infused oil, so it's unclear on where any chili could have come from.  How MUCH does it taste like chilies?  Why chipotles in particular, is there a smoky flavor as well?

Comment: It's the usual yellowish color, although sometimes I think it has been greener. Chipotles because of that particular smoky smell they have, although not actually hot. It's enough that when I heat it up in the pan, I smell the chili smell from across the room, rather than the olive oil smell. It's in the flavor as well -- there might be some "green" flavor under it, but it's mostly this mild chipotle flavor. No real pepperiness, but that's I think usual for this brand.

Comment: Wait ... is the smell/flavor *just* smokiness, or does it also have fruity and spicy notes?  Because if it's just smokiness, then I can think of a number of ways the oil could end up like that.